# Where to initialize BillingClient from Google Play Billing Library?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

I’d like to use the [Google Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html) for in-app billing in my Android app. When the app launches, I’d like to initialize the [BillingClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.html), start the connection, and retrieve some product data. The actual purchase would happen from a different activity (not the launch activity).

Should I make some kind of singleton billing manager that contains the BillingClient, so I can start it when the app launches and still use it in the other activity? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing) provided by Google. In this example, they use additional `BillingManager` class which can be accessed from different places of your application but it isn't a singleton because it's not only about `BillingClient` you also have to have `PurchasesUpdatedListener` which is receiving updates from the `BillingManager`.

If you want to make `BillingClient` a singleton you can use [BillingManager](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive_v2/shared-module/src/main/java/com/example/billingmodule/billing/BillingManager.java) from the sample app and manage the list of `BillingUpdatesListener` by yourself.

Comment: I’m not very familiar with the Android system (working on my first app made from scratch), but is it self to keep my `BillingClient` in a singleton for the whole lifetime of the app? Won’t it give problems with the connection etc.?

Comment: @Jonathan keeping `BillingClient` as a singleton for the whole lifetime of the app it's not a problem but you have to manage `PurchasesUpdatedListener`'s in few different places where you need them. In your case in two places. First is the app start to retrieve some product data and second when you are initiating payment process.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following approach:

```
mBillingManager = new BillingManager(this, getUpdateListener());

mBillingManager.startServiceConnection(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // Do AnyThing Here
      }
});
```